# Connection Timeout error Java eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am  new to Java. I am currently getting a connection timeout i don't understand why.

Code:

```
final HttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
      HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {

        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {


          request.getHeaders().setBasicAuthentication(userId, password);
          request.setParser(new JsonObjectParser(JSON_FACTORY));
          request.setReadTimeout(120000);
        }
      });
```

additional information on responses

```
request.setUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(
        new HttpBackOffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(new ExponentialBackOff()));

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try 
    {

      response = request.execute();

      if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatusCodes.STATUS_CODE_OK) {
        try {
           //do something here 
            }


    }
```

Currently getting the following error not sure how to resolve this.

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(ConnPoolByRoute.java:345)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute$1.getPoolEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:228)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:172)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:390)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
at com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest.execute(ApacheHttpRequest.java:67)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
```

Comment: It means the remote endpoint to which you tried to connect did not respond within the time given.  Without more detail, such as the remote address, your question is not otherwise answerable.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: how do i extend the time?

Comment: The issue is not the time.  The problem is there's nothing listening at the other end to respond to the connection.  You have to tell us the remote address to which you're trying to connect, and show the network(s) between where you are and where the remote is.

Comment: Note:  i get the error message not on the first try i do get responses from the endpoint/ remote address.

Comment: Then see @JackHarkness's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your timeout is most likely caused by a connection leak. To fix this, your response entity needs to be consumed, and the content stream associated with the entity must be closed.

One way to do this is to use EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity()) or EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity()). Either of these will ensure that the entities content is fully consumed and the content stream, if it exists, is closed correctly. Both of these functions release all resources held by your response entity.

Example:

```
try {
 EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
} catch (Exception e) {} finally {
 response.releaseConnection();
}
```

Comment: i'll add some information. I m new to Java. somebody else wrote the code and i'm looking at it.